# How can I cycle through an array of images using state/props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native app where I want to pass in an object array using state/props that contains images.  I want to cycle through the images when a button is pressed.  I have been working on this for a while now, and can't figure it out.  Would someone mind taking a look?  I'm new to react-native so if you think I should be doing this differently please let me know. Thanks!!

I have been going over javascript/react-native for a while now and can't figure out how I should do this.

```
//file1 (ImageHolder.js)
import type {ImageSourcePropType } from "react- native/Libraries/Image?ImageSourcePropType";

export type ImageHolder = {
  id: string,
  actualimage: ImageSourcePropType,
};

//file2(App.js)

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react- native';
import { type ImageHolder } from './ImageHolder'

const imageholder2: ImageHolder[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    actualimage: require("./images/image1.jpeg"),
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    actualimage: require("./images/image2.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    actualimage: require("./images/image3.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    actualimage: require("./images/image4.jpg"),
  },
];



export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Image
        style = {{
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
        source = {require('./images/image1.jpeg')} />
      </View>
      <View>
      <Button title= "Press me"/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I simply want to be able to cycle through the images when pressing the button and somehow be able to access what I'm on.

Comment: Use a state variable to store the current image index. When the button is pressed, increase the variable / reset it to 0.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  How do I access the imageholder actual image from a state variable that equals the id though?  I am new to react, I apologize if I am missing something simple.

Comment: Something like `imageholder2[this.state.currentImageId].actualimage` will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the current image index in a state and increase ir when you press the button.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0)

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {
            imageholder2[currentImageIndex] &&
              <Image
                key={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].id}
                style = {{
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                }}
                source={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].actualimage} 
              />
        }
      </View>
      <View>
      <Button 
          title= "Press me" 
          onPress={() => setCurrentImageIndex(currentImageIndex == imageholder2.length - 1 ? 
              0 : 
              currentImageIndex + 1
          )}
      />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also, it would be better if you keep the images in a state.

Sorry for not giving the typescript answer.

Comment: Please note that `.map` is a native method of Arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: It's probably better to pass something a little more explicit than the image index in the array (incase that order changed). so `onClick={() => handleImageClick(img.id)}` would probably be better :) +1 from me!

Comment: Hi guys.  I think my plan is going to be to store an index in the state and then increase it when the button is pressed.  How do I access the imageholder actual image from a state variable that equals the id though? I am new to react, I apologize if I am missing something simple.

Comment: @Matt123 what do you mean by `access the imageholder` ? What do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to display the next image. But I want to access it by a state Id that equals the imageholder id

Comment: You want to have a button that change the image that is showing? Ow now I see in your question, I will fix that

Comment: @Matt123 just edited, check my edit please. Do you want to keep the `id` in the state or the index is ok?

Comment: It worked!! Thanks @Vencovsky et all!!  I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

Call Carousel Component and pass an array of four images.

```
<Carousel
    images={[
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg",
    ]}
  />
```

Then this is my carousel component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Carousel(props) {
  const { images } = props;
  let [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  function increase() {
    if (imageIndex <= 2) {
      setImageIndex(imageIndex + 1);
    } else {
      setImageIndex(0);
    }
  }

  function decrease() {
    if (imageIndex > 0) {
      setImageIndex(imageIndex - 1);
    } else {
      setImageIndex(3);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrease}>Left</button>
      <img src={images[imageIndex]} alt="carousel" />

      <button onClick={increase}>Right</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousel;
```